# How to show image inside PopUp via View Model in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

Hi I'm a newbie to windows store apps and i want to create a pop up that'll show image .I'm currently using Prism framework and tried many things.However , I'm successfully able to launch the pop up using code behind file but i need it from View Model class. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default winrt popups but if you want popups developed by yourself this is the way.

Create modal dialog user control, structure is following

```
<Grid>
 <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.4"/>
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticelAlignment="Center">
    <!-- your popup xaml -->
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Of course, you have to set ViewModel in some way, e.g. through ViewModelLocator

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}, Path=ModalDialog}">
```

Add this user control to your main view ( root view ) or to all views where you want to have popup.

```
<controls:ModalDialog Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

After this you can implement some service or use messenger to show dialogs. I know that it is maybe not so understandable but it is difficult to describe in all details. Feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I need to ask one more thing in this context that how can we manipulate IsOpen flag of popup through view model property??

Comment: I'm using MvvmLight Messenger class. You can inject Messenger to all ViewModels that should call to open ModalDialog and ModalDialogViewModel can receive messages and set Visibility to true